# Wait for react-promise to resolve before render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a large set of data that I'm retrieving from an API. I believe the problem is that my component is calling the renderMarkers function before the data is received from the promise.

So I am wondering how I can wait for the promise to resolve the data completely before calling my renderMarkers function?

```
class Map extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.props)
  new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map, {
    zoom: 12,
    center: {
      lat: this.props.route.lat,
      lng: this.props.route.lng
    }
  })
}

componentWillMount() {
  this.props.fetchWells()
}

renderMarkers() {
  return this.props.wells.map((wells) => {
    console.log(wells)
  })
}

render() {
  return (
    <div id="map" ref="map">
      {this.renderMarkers()}
    </div>
  )
 }
} 

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { wells: state.wells.all };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchWells })(Map);
```

Comment: Fetch server data in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method. Look [this tweet](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/790581793397305345) of Dan Abramov

Comment: Thanks, I switched it up, however the component is still calling the render function before the data is returned

Answer (score 41):

You could do something like this to show a *Loader* until all the info is fetched:

```
class Map extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = { wells: [] }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchWells()
      .then(res => this.setState({ wells: res.wells }) )
  }

  render () {
    const { wells } = this.state
    return wells.length ? this.renderWells() : (
      <span>Loading wells...</span>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 27):

for functional components with hooks:

```
    function App() {
        
          const [nodes, setNodes] = useState({});
          const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
        
          useEffect(() => {
            getAllNodes();
          }, []);
        
          const getAllNodes = () => {
            axios.get("http://localhost:5001/").then((response) => {
              setNodes(response.data);
              setLoading(false);
            });
          };
        
        
          if (isLoading) {
            return <div className="App">Loading...</div>;
          }
          return (
            <>
              <Container allNodes={nodes} />
            </>
        
          );
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Calling the render function before the API call is finished is fine. The `wells` is an empty array (initial state), you simply render nothing. And after receiving the data from API, your component will automatically re-render because the update of props (redux store). So I don't see the problem.

If you really want to prevent it from rendering before receiving API data, just check that in your render function, for example:

```
if (this.props.wells.length === 0) {
  return null
}

return (
  <div id="map" ref="map">
    {this.renderMarkers()}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Notice the use case you mention is just one possibility. Actually if you already have data, let's say an entire `enterprises` list and then you want to go somewhere listing just a few enterprises, then you first will see the entire list and then it will shrink. That seems weird. So, before showing a filtered list one should be able check if Promise is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

So I have the similar problem, with react and found out solution on my own. by using Async/Await calling react 
Code snippet is below please try this.

```
 import Loader from 'react-loader-spinner'

 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {loading : true}
  }
  getdata = async (data) => {
    return await data; 
  }
  getprops  = async (data) =>{
    if (await this.getdata(data)){
      this.setState({loading: false})
    }
  }
  render() {
  var { userInfo , userData} = this.props;
    if(this.state.loading == true){
      this.getprops(this.props.userData);
    } 
    else{
//perform action after getting value in props
    }
    return (
      <div>
      {
           this.state.loading ? 
             <Loader
               type="Puff"
               color="#00BFFF"
               height={100}
               width={100}
             />
           :    
              <MyCustomComponent/> // place your react component here
      }
      </div>
      )
}
```