# React - wait for promise before render

Tags: reactjs, async-await, render

I can't figure this out, if you can point me to right direction. On my NavMenu.js I have LogIn (two inputs and a submit button, on which I call `handleSubmit()`

In `handleSubmit()` I am checking for user login credentials which works great, but after I confirm login, i procede with doing next fetch for checking user roles (and returning promise) and visibility in application

Helper.js

```
function getAllRoles(formName, sessionVarName) {

    var roleData = [];
    var roleId = sessionStorage.getItem('UserLoggedRoleId');

    fetch('api/User/GetUserRole/', {
    'method': 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    'body':
        JSON.stringify({
            'roleId': roleId,
            'formName': formName
        })
    }).then(roleResponse => roleResponse.json())
    .then(data => {
        sessionStorage.setItem(sessionVarName, JSON.stringify(data));
        roleData = data;
    });

  var result = Promise.resolve(roleData)

  return result;
}

function checkRoleVisibility(userRoles, role) {} <-- return true or false

export {
  getAllRoles ,
  checkRoleVisibility   
};
```

In NavMenu.js

```
import { getAllRoles, checkRoleVisibility } from './common/Helper';

handleSubmit() {

 fetch('api/User/UserAuthentification/', 
 ....then(response => {
       if (response.ok) {
               this.setState(prevState => ({ userLogged: !prevState.userLogged }))

               response.json().then(value => {

               sessionStorage.setItem('UserLogged', true);
               sessionStorage.setItem('UserLabelSession', this.state.userLabel);
               sessionStorage.setItem('UserLoggedRoleId', value.userRole.roleID);

               getAllRoles('NavMenu', 'UserLoggedRoles')
                     .then(roleData => {
                            this.setState({
                                loggedUserRoles: roleData,
                                loading: false
                            });
                        });

               this.props.alert.success("Dobro dosli");
        })
   }
}
```

But here comes the problem, is that in `render()` itself, I have a control `navBar` which calls

```
checkRoleVisibility(this.state.loggedUserRoles, 'SeeTabRadniNalozi')
```

from helper, which send `this.state.loggedUserRoles` as parameter, which suppose to be filled in fetch from `handleSubmit()` but it's undefined, fetch finish, set `loading` on true, rendering completes and it doesn't show anything

I have `this.state.loading` and based on it I show control ...

```
    let navMenu = this.state.loading ? <div className="loaderPosition">
        <Loader type="Watch" color="#1082F3" height="200" width="200" />
    </div> : !this.state.userLogged ? logInControl : navBar;
```

If I put a breakpoint on controler I can see my method is being called by `getAllRoles` function, but also I can see that application keep rendering on going and doesn't wait for promise to return to fill state of `loggedUserRoles`.

So question is, why rendering doesn't wait for my role fetch nor doesn't wait for promise to resolve before setting loading on true?

I checked this answer [Wait for react-promise to resolve before render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42132290/wait-for-react-promise-to-resolve-before-render) and I put `this.setState({ loading: false });` on `componentDidMount()` but then loading div is shown full time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see and understand is, that you're calling

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ userLogged: !prevState.userLogged }))
```

if the response is okay. This will lead in an asynchronous call from React to set the new State whenever it has time for it.

But you need the resource from

```
this.setState({
  loggedUserRoles: roleData,
  loading: false
});
```

whenever you want to set `userLogged` to true, right?

So it might be that React calls render before you set the `loggedUserRoles` but after `userLogged` is set to true. That would result in an error if I understand you correctly.

You could simply set the `userLogged` state with the others together like this:

```
this.setState({
  userLogged: true,
  loggedUserRoles: roleData,
  loading: false
});
```

EDIT:

Moreover you want to change your Promise creation inside of getAllRoles. You're returning

```
var result = Promise.resolve(roleData)

return result;
```

This will directly lead to the empty array since this is the initial value of `roleData`. Therefore you're always returning an empty array from that method and don't bother about the fetched result.

You've multiple ways to solve this. I would prefer the clean and readable way of using async/await:

```
async getAllRoles(formName, sessionVarName){
  var roleId = sessionStorage.getItem('UserLoggedRoleId');

  const response = await fetch(...);
  const data = response.json();

  sessionStorage.setItem(sessionVarName, JSON.stringify(data));
  return data;
```

Or if you want to stay with Promise:

```
function getAllRoles(formName, sessionVarName){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var roleId = sessionStorage.getItem('UserLoggedRoleId');

    fetch(...)
    .then(roleResponse => roleResponse.json())
    .then(data => {
      sessionStorage.setItem(sessionVarName, JSON.stringify(data));
      resolve(data);
    });
```

Comment: I just tried that, and added `console.log(userRoles);` in `function checkRoleVisibility` still getting empty array after login. But I am sure that my call returns data, because when I had all functions in `NavMenu.js` everything worked perfectly, I just moved this two functions in new `.js` because I have to call them on all pages

Comment: Which value does ```.then(roleData =>``` get you? I think this will always be an empty array since it can directly be resolved from ```var result = Promise.resolve(roleData)```.

Comment: I figured it out ... key was to make `function getAllRoles` to be `async` then to `let result = await Promise.resolve(roleData)` ... so after user login, after 1-2 seconds tab shows up

Comment: Yes, I just added this to my answer as an EDIT

Comment: For the record, for someone reason Promise seems to be working faster than async   calling ... just in case someone reads this answer